# How to center text in second line of textview to another line?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

When I set a long text to a textview it breaks to another line and looks like this:
[image]

But I want second line to be centered instead of being aligned to left side of parent. Is there any simple way to center this or I have to create 2nd textview and write some boilerplate code?

if anyone curious, here's the code I use:

```
<View
        android:id="@+id/view_top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.3"
        android:background="@color/colorBlack"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cpu_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/view_top"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/view_top"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:text="@{viewModel.mProcessorName}"
        tools:text="Qualcomm Technologies, Inc MSM8940"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just add this attribute to your `TextView`

```
  android:gravity="center"
```

Comment: Works fine, dunno why I didn't know that. I'll accept your answer in few minutes